# Ckeditor not working with angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I am having issue with ckeditor4.When I run it independently its working fine.But when I trying to run it with my angular app its not working.Here is my sample code:

```
 var initSample = ( function() {
    var wysiwygareaAvailable = isWysiwygareaAvailable(),
        isBBCodeBuiltIn = !!CKEDITOR.plugins.get( 'bbcode' );

    return function() {
        var editorElement = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'editor' );

        // :(((
        if ( isBBCodeBuiltIn ) {
            editorElement.setHtml(
                'Hello world!\n\n' +
                'I\'m an instance of [url=http://ckeditor.com]CKEditor[/url].'
            );
        }

        // Depending on the wysiwygare plugin availability initialize classic or inline editor.
        if ( wysiwygareaAvailable ) {
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
        } else {
            editorElement.setAttribute( 'contenteditable', 'true' );
            CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor' );

            // TODO we can consider displaying some info box that
            // without wysiwygarea the classic editor may not work.
        }
    };

    function isWysiwygareaAvailable() {
        // If in development mode, then the wysiwygarea must be available.
        // Split REV into two strings so builder does not replace it :D.
        if ( CKEDITOR.revision == ( '%RE' + 'V%' ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return !!CKEDITOR.plugins.get( 'wysiwygarea' );
    }
}
```

When I console after `"isBBCodeBuiltIn = !!CKEDITOR.plugins.get( 'bbcode' )"` line its consoling fine.But it is not entering inside `return function() { }`.Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't see anything related to AngularJS and/or your app so no...I have no suggestion.

Comment: Do you load all the prerequisites for ckeditor?

Comment: I just posted a piece of code where its stucking when i run it with my application.Independently its working fine.

Comment: where is that code called from? needs to be in directive. Suggest getting an angular CKEditor module that is already well tested

Comment: @Lelio.. Yes all the ckeditor file are included..

Comment: Do you guys have any link for angular ckeditor directive?

Comment: Jquery veriosn  2.1.4...